# Convert dataframe index values into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe that looks like this:
[image: stats dataframe]

What I would love to do, is to turn the `PTS` and `REB` value into respective columns with each value underneath, like

```
PTS   | REB
----------
14.29 | 5.71
```

Is this possible? I have intermediate experience with pandas, but through googling and the docs, it doesn't appear to be the easiest find.

Thanks!

Comment: Just transpose: `df.T`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the transpose functionality.

```
df_transpose = df.T
```

or

```
df_transpose = df.transpose()
```

Here is the link to the doc:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html